# Folder Structure in Client Side Graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo

I need a recommendation for the making the client side folder structure for implementing react app with graphql. I already have all the APIs ready in the backend and I need to make sure that I have a good client-side structure for implementing the frontend app using react js so that I don't have a problem when the app becomes large in future.